# How do I install VMware Player (from a .bundle file)?

Tags: software-installation, vmware-player

I downloaded VMware Player 5.0.1, it comes in a file with `.bundle` extension. How do I install it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Open a terminal, cd to the directory where the file is and type

```
sudo sh *filename*.bundle
```

Comment: grumble grumble they couldn't have put this on the download page could they.

Comment: anyidea how to uninstall this ???

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively give execute privileges to the .bundle file. The execute it with root privileges.

```
chmod u+x filename.bundle
sudo ./filename.bundle
```