# linux-headers-3.16.0-36-generic can`t be installed (15.04)

Tags: kernel, vmware-player

I recently installed vmware player 6.0.5 for linux x86 and before installaton procces I run the command :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

[sudo] password for bogdan:

after I recive this :

```
Citire liste de pachete... Terminat
Se construiește arborele de dependență       
Se citesc informațiile de stare... Terminat
Pachetul linux-headers-3.16.0-36-generic nu este disponibil, dar este menționat de către alt pachet.
Aceasta ar putea însemna că pachetul lipsește, s-a învechit, sau
este disponibil numai din altă sursă

E: Pachetul 'linux-headers-3.16.0-36-generic' nu are candidat pentru instalare
```

how to fix this error ? I run ubuntu 15.04

Comment: That kernel is for Ubuntu 14.04, which is probably why it doesn't install.

Comment: Try to run sudo apt-get update and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It will not install using apt-get since it is not listed as part of the 15.04 distribution. You can still manually download and install it.

You can download the package from here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.16.0-36_3.16.0-36.48_all.deb

You may need to install also linux-headers-3.16.0-36-generic_3.16.0-36.48_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.16.0-36-generic_3.16.0-36.48_amd64.deb

Depends on the architecture, you might need the 386 version instead: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.16.0-36-generic_3.16.0-36.48_i386.dep

Answer (score 0):

> I recently installed vmware player 6.0.5 for linux x86 and before installaton procces I run the command :
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
> ```

## Why?

Running this command is unnecessary. It's not a prerequisite or dependency for VMware Player I just tested it, I cloned and upgraded my Utopic VM (kernel 3.16) to Vivid (kernel 3.19) and [installed the product](https://askubuntu.com/q/265192/40581) the way you're supposed to. The installer does everything on it's own.

The more interesting question is: **Why are you running this kernel on 15.04?** It's only kept as a backup for certain events and this is not one of it. Also it's not the kernel that GRUB runs by default.

Your problem here is that you run an unnecessary command which you do not understand (it installs headers for the currently *running* kernel) in a context where it's not supposed to be run and you interpret the message as a "computer error" without checking what you could have done wrong. It's not the machine that looks like it does anything wrong or stupid here from my perspective. Stop pasting administrative commands to the terminal without thinking.

Comment: Because, here is one good reason to use older kernel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/617413/why-ubuntu-15-04-with-kernel-3-19-0-15-is-using-significantly-more-power and if one need to compile kernel modules, one need the headers.