# Why Ubuntu 15.04 with kernel 3.19.0-15 is using significantly more power?

Tags: kernel, battery, cpu, 15.04, macbook-air

I've recently upgraded to 15.04 and immediately noticed significantly faster battery depletion and warmer case. My MacBook Air 6,2 would easily hold 10-12 hours on battery power with Ubuntu 14.10 and now it only holds 3 hours(!) I've tried using tlp, removing powerclamp (I noticed 4 x kidle_inject) and playing with other parameters. The current workaround is booting with the older and better 3.16.0-36.

Does anyone else experiencing the same? Anyone knows how to solve this? I can provide any information and will try anything to solve this.

**EDIT:** Per a request in the comments, this is the same with both kernels:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver
intel_pstate
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
```

**EDIT 2:** sudo turbostat -S sleep 300

```
With 3.16.0-36:
Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c3  CPU%c6  CPU%c7 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 Pkg%pc7 Pkg%pc8 Pkg%pc9 Pk%pc10 PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt
      82    4.85    1689    2299       0   10.08    1.91    0.93   82.23      52      52   20.91    2.16    6.80   45.68    0.00    0.00    0.00    2.07    0.43    0.07

With 3.19.0-15:
 Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c3  CPU%c6  CPU%c7 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 Pkg%pc7 Pkg%pc8 Pkg%pc9 Pk%pc10 PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt
     111    4.82    2295    2300       0   10.17    2.63    1.03   81.35      58      58   18.73   49.94    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    4.54    0.86    0.66
```

**EDIT 3:** turbostat when completely idle and X turned off

```
With 3.16.0-36:
Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c3  CPU%c6  CPU%c7 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 Pkg%pc7 Pkg%pc8 Pkg%pc9 Pk%pc10 PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt 
       3    0.30    1133    2300       0    0.53    0.03    0.00   99.14      40      40   18.66    0.28    0.90   78.52    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.97    0.01    0.00

With 3.19.0-15:
 Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c3  CPU%c6  CPU%c7 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 Pkg%pc7 Pkg%pc8 Pkg%pc9 Pk%pc10 PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt
      13    0.64    1970    2300       0    0.89    0.12    0.01   98.35      46      46   18.25   78.78    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    2.28    0.12    0.00
```

Comment: 3.19 may be a bit new compared to 3.16, and newer kernels tend to have more unfixed bugs then older ones.

Comment: Your problem is very interesting. In addition to what Mike said, it might also be worth trying a newer kernel, [like 4.0.1 or 4.1RC1](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) to determine if the problem has been fixed, but the fix just hasn't been backported yet. Please add to your question which processor you are using, which CPU frequency scaling driver you are using and which frequency governor it is using. `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"`  `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver`  `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Comment: Thanks @DougSmythies Posted info as requested and will try new kernel soon.

Comment: @DougSmythies I'm now using 4.0.1. It is not running as hot as 3.19 but also not as cold as 3.16. The case is bit warm and my calculation shows about 6 hours on battery.

Comment: Can you use turbostat to determine if the power consumptions differences are processor related or graphics related? I would just run it for say 5 minutes: `sudo turbostat -S sleep 300`. Are you comfortable compiling the kernel?

Comment: @DougSmythies working on turbostat. Yes I'm comfortable compiling the kernel. (I wonder, how would I install 4.0.1 otherwise? see comment above)

Comment: The turbostat data doesn't explain all the power difference, but is significant. You should verify with a couple of more samples, and note there might be a power drop 10 minutes after boot, there is on my system. Also, any screen blanking and locking should be turned off. I thought you might have downloaded the 4.0.1 kernel from the link I gave. Anyway, we will want to obtain some perf record data, and that will need a patch added to the kernel (the patch will be in kernel 4.2RC1, I think). It is late in my time zone, we'll have to pick this up tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you @DougSmythies. I missed the link to the kernel-ppa. anyway, I will collect more samples tomorrow (should I compare 3.16.0 to 3-19.0 or to 4.0.1?)

Comment: Added more samples, this time when completely idle. I've monitored to make sure no cron jobs or other processes are running. It is pretty clear that the newer kernel doesn't reach pkg%pc7 and draws more power.

Comment: This thing said you wanted to move to a chat, which I did, but you are not there.

Comment: I can't figure out how to write anything in chat. It said I must login into stackexchange, which I'm but still no good. Compiling the kernel is way easier comparing to that.

Comment: OK, I've figured it out. See you in chat.

Comment: After bisecting the kernel here is where it started: 7bc5a2bad0b8d9d1ac9f7b8b33150e4ddf197334 is the first bad commit 
commit 7bc5a2bad0b8d9d1ac9f7b8b33150e4ddf197334 
Author: Matthew Garrett <*> 
Date: Sat Sep 20 13:19:47 2014 +0200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a kernel bug reported here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92111 (many thanks @DougSmythies)

Workaround: add `acpi_osi=` to the kernel cmdline in `/etc/default/grub` e.g.:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="hid_apple.iso_layout=0 elevator=cfq acpi_osi="
```

run `sudo update-grub` afterwards and reboot.

This will most likely disable thunderbolt.

Comment: Clarification: This will disable thunderbolt hot-plugging. If you first plug your thunderbolt device, and then turn on the computer, it will work as expected.

Comment: Addendum: while my answer solved most of the battery consumption issues, there are still other issues.  I'm currently unable to work on this and I switched back to MacOS and ubuntu under vmware.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue [92111](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92111) caused the power usage increase.